# How I delete custom dexterity objects in Plone 4?

Tags: python, plone, dexterity, plone-4.x

I'm trying delete some custom dexterity objects, bellow have snipets code of this custom object.

```
class IDigitalFile(model.Schema):
        """Dexterity-Schema
        """

    ...

    directives.read_permission(auto="cmf.ManagePortal")
    directives.write_permission(auto="cmf.ManagePortal")
    fieldset('Admins Only', fields=['auto', 'uploded_at', 'codLote'] )
    auto = schema.Bool(
        title=_(u"Upload via Script?"),
        required=True,
        default=False,
    )
    ...
```

And I try use `sudo plone_daemon bin/client2 -O Plone debug` and apply this code:

```
from zope.site.hooks import setSite
site = 'Plone'
context = app[site]
setSite(context)
portal_catalog = context.portal_catalog
itens = portal_catalog(portal_type='digitalfile', path='/ged/')
print itens
```

After rum this script my output is `[]`, just epmty but if i use the similar code in `ZMI` I have all brains.

So, in `ZMI` we can't user methods to delete 'cuz have restrictions.
And my goal is delete all objects `digitalfile`if flag `True`in `auto`field.

How can I do it if my results are empties?
Or what I did wrong for output is empty?

[UPDATE 1]

This problem apper to me:

```
zero@srv-d:/opt/Plone439/zeocluster$ sudo -u plone_daemon bin/client2 -O Plone debug
Starting debugger (the name "app" is bound to the top-level Zope object)
2017-03-31 10:09:04 WARNING ZODB.blob (18048) Blob dir /opt/Plone439/zeocluster/var/blobstorage/ has insecure mode setting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/Plone439/zeocluster/parts/client2/bin/interpreter", line 281, in <module>
    exec(_val)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/Plone439/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.24-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/BaseRequest.py", line 623, in traverse
    response.unauthorized()
  File "/opt/Plone439/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.24-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/HTTPResponse.py", line 756, in unauthorized
    raise Unauthorized, m
zExceptions.unauthorized.Unauthorized: You are not authorized to access this resource.
```

[UPDATE 2 - SOLVED]

Maybe have a easy way to do, but in this moment, this script solved my problem and I'm sharing if someone need...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from zope.site.hooks import setSite
from plone import api
import transaction

# Setting the plone portal in var context
site = 'Plone'
context = app[site]
setSite(context)

# grabbing portal_catalog tool
portal_catalog = context.portal_catalog

# setting the user that have permission
with api.env.adopt_user(username='admin'):
    # grabbing all items digitalfile
    brains = portal_catalog(portal_type='digitalfile', path='/ged')

for brain in brains:
    if 'TO BE DELETE' in brain.Description:
        item = api.content.get(path=brain.getPath())
        api.content.delete(obj=item)
        transaction.commit()
```

Comment: You may have better luck posting questions on our forum, https://community.plone.org (more eyeballs), though I will post a link on the forum to your question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might mean that you need "security clearance" to access the brains/objects.

Normally portal catalog search will only return results for objects for which you have access permissions. In ZMI it works because you are logged-in as an admin (or a site manager), while command line scripts [do not have user information set by default](https://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/misc/commandline.html#posing-as-user). For example, if objects are not published (in `private` state), they will not show up in catalog search in a command line script.

If you have [plone.api](https://docs.plone.org/develop/plone.api/docs/) installed, you can use "api.env.adopt_user" to run a command with the specified user:

```
from plone import api

with api.env.adopt_user(username="admin"):
    items = portal_catalog(portal_type='digitalfile', path='/ged/')
```

Alternatively, you can use `portal_catalog.unrestrictedSearchResults` to ignore security checks when performing the search:

```
items = portal_catalog.unrestrictedSearchResults(
    portal_type='digitalfile', path='/ged/')
```

I remember that in the later case sometimes I had to use `brain._unrestrictedGetObject()` to get the actual object, but now it seems to work also with regular `brain.getObject()` (perhaps depends on Zope/Plone version used).

Comment: It's Worked like a glove in both cases!. Great Thx.

Answer (score 2):

I think portal_type is 'Dexterity Item' in this case. Try `portal_catalog(object_provides=IDigitalFile.__identifier__)` instead.
You don't need the path argument, if you want to do this globally.

Comment: May the problem to access the object is caused by the `Exceptions.unauthorized.Unauthorized: You are not authorized to access this resource`, see my `UPDATE`

Comment: Nice, so now you get the content, but cannot access it yet. Jure's answer will solve that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43155696/2219976

Comment: Yes! Great Thx for your time. I will finish the script and will post!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the id of the Plone site in the path for the catalog search: `portal_catalog(portal_type='digitalfile', path='/Plone/ged/')`